# Let $X$ be a topological space and $A \subset X$ a set with $\partial A = \emptyset$. Show that $\chi_A : X \to \Bbb R$ is continuous.

Tags: general-topology

> Let $X$ be a topological space and $A \subset X$ a set with $\partial A = \emptyset$. Show that $\chi_A : X \to \Bbb R$ is continuous.

I need to use this result in a problem, but I'm not sure how continuity follows. Clearly $\chi_A(A) ) =  \{1\}$ and $\chi_A(X \setminus A )= \{0\}$. So if $U$ is open in $\Bbb R$ I think I need to check three cases.

First when $1 \in U$ and second when $0 \in U$ and lastly when $1$ and $0$ both in $U$.

If $1 \in U$, then $\chi_A^{-1}(U) \subset A$ and if $0 \in U$, then $\chi_A^{-1}(U) \subset X \setminus A$. If both are in $U$, then I don't think I can make any other conclusions oterhthan that $\chi_{A}^{-1}(U) \subset X$.

How do I conclude openness from these facts?

Comment: If $\partial A=\emptyset$ then $\mathring A=\overline A$. Then $A\subset\overline A =\mathring A\subset A$, so these inclusions are equalities. Therefore $A$ is closed and open, or equivalently $A$ and $A^\complement$ are closed (and open). You can use that fact to show the desired continuity.

Comment: How will this alone prove continuity as I still have that the preimages are just subsets of $A$ and $A^c$? @Will

Comment: A map is continuous iff the preimage of any open set is an open set.